# Magento Observer for Admin Sales order Address update

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer, adminhtml, sales-order

Does Magento have any observer or event that trigger when the Order Address is updated by the admin? Is there any Observer or alternate way to find out when the order address is changed..

i tried using the observer
`controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addressSave` but i cannot get any order related information and `sales_order_address_save_after` is being triggered when the order is placed too ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best approach would be using `sales_order_address_save_after` event, if you are not creating orders through admin

You can easily validate if a request is from admin or not using this 2 validations:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()
Mage::getDesign()->getArea() == 'adminhtml'
```

Then just do nothing in your observer if request is frontend

Other than that, you can define your observers in **config.xml** files for a specific areas, such as `adminhtml`

```
<config>
...
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_address_save_after>
                <observers>
                ...
                </observers>
            </sales_order_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Likewise, I'd use the request code validation, just to be sure

Hope this helps

Comment: That is a great idea.. Thank you so much.. should definitely  go with `sales_order_address_save_after` with those 2 validations but is there any solution for "creating orders through admin" ..so i think can we use `sales_order_address_save_before` and check whether the Order is already created or not??  is it possible to check this way??  thanks for the help :)

Comment: I suppose you can identify that case with some more specific events, take a look at Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController file & play with it. Feel free to accept the answer as valid if this helped ;)